# Issue with Accumulator in XSLT3.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I have the below data from one data source,

```
    <Reference>
      <Worker>
        <Employee_ID>1234</Employee_ID>
        <Salary_Type>H</Salary_Type>
      </Worker>
      <Worker>
        <Employee_ID>5678</Employee_ID>
        <Salary_Type>H</Salary_Type>
      </Worker>
    </Reference>
```

the below data come from another data source,

```
    <root>
      <row>
         <ID>1234</ID>
         <ADDR>ABC</ADDR>
         <PHONE>9999999998</PHONE>            
         <SAL>S</SAL>          
      </row>
      <row>
        <ID>5678</ID>
        <ADDR>ABD</ADDR>
        <PHONE>9999999999</PHONE>  
        <SAL>S</SAL>
      </row>
    </root>
```

I have merged the data from these data sources and have the following data,

```
    <root>
      <Reference>
        <Worker>
          <EmployeeID>1234</Employee_ID>
          <SalaryType>H</Salary_Type>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
          <EmployeeID>5678</Employee_ID>
          <SalaryType>H</Salary_Type>
        </Worker>
    </Reference>
    <root>
      <row>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <ADDR>ABC</ADDR>
        <PHONE>9999999998</PHONE>            
        <SAL>S</SAL>          
      </row>
      <row>
        <ID>5678</ID>
        <ADDR>ABD</ADDR>
        <PHONE>9999999999</PHONE>  
        <SAL>S</SAL>
      </row>
     </root>
    </root>
```

In XSLT3.0 I m trying to replace the value of `<SAL>` with value of `<SalaryType>` with the following code, buts its not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">
   <xsl:mode streamable="no" on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="#all"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:accumulator name="EIDKey" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="/root/Reference/Worker/EmployeeID/text()" select="."/> 
   </xsl:accumulator>
   <xsl:accumulator name="PayTypeLookup" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map {}"     
      streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="/root/Reference/Worker/SalaryType/text()"  
         select="map:put($value, accumulator-before('EIDKey'), string(.))"/>
   </xsl:accumulator>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
         <xsl:for-each select="root/root/row"> 
            <row>
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </row>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="SAL">
      <xsl:variable name="PayType" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
      <SAL><xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('PayTypeLookup')($PayType)"/></SAL> 
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need the final output like below, can you please help? Thanks in advance

```
    <root>
      <row>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <ADDR>ABC</ADDR>
        <PHONE>9999999998</PHONE>            
        <SAL>H</SAL>          
      </row>
      <row>
        <ID>5678</ID>
        <ADDR>ABD</ADDR>
        <PHONE>9999999999</PHONE>  
        <SAL>H</SAL>
      </row>
    </root>
```

Comment: It seems rather convoluted to merge your two data files into one and then to use accumulators to build a map corresponding to the data in the first file. Why not just access the first file in non-streaming mode and build the map directly?

Comment: @Michael Kay Thanks for your reply. The idea is not to use the maps.

Comment: Please remove excessive indentation from your code blocks (see [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another accumulator

```
<xsl:accumulator name="rowID" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="/root/root/row/ID/text()" select="."/> 
</xsl:accumulator>
```

and then you can use

```
<xsl:template match="SAL">
  <SAL><xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('PayTypeLookup')(accumulator-before('rowID'))"/></SAL> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.  Is there a way in which I can replace the for-each with apply-templates in my XSLT?

Comment: @Arun, sure, you can change that template `<xsl:template match="/">` to simply create `<root><xsl:apply-templates select="root/root/row"/></root>`, that way you process the same `row` elements and the identity template declared for the mode takes care of copying them and processing their child nodes.